# WinForms and disposing custom controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, dispose

I have the following class:

```
public class NewListBox : ListBox
    {
        public NewListBox()
        {
        }

        private ImageList _myImageList;

        public ImageList ImageList
        {
            get { return _myImageList; }
            set { _myImageList = value; }
        }
     }
```

I am interested in whether disposing of this object will trigger the disposal of fields on the object, such as the ImageList, or should i implement (override) the Dispose method and do this work myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add the ImageList to your control's Components collection, then the base-class implementation of Dispose will Dispose everything in that collection, and you won't have to override Dispose yourself.

If you have any members that are IDisposable but are not Components, then you will have to override Dispose in your control and Dispose them yourself.

(I am using the term Component in the strict sense of objects that derive from System.ComponentModel.Component).

Comment: Is there any consistent pattern to which WinForms controls take ownership of IDisposable properties and which ones do not?  My understanding is that with something like an `Image` property (which a control typically does not own), code which sets the `Image` property of a control to a picture which will be needed for no purpose outside that control should also attach itself to that control's `Disposed` event, and `Dispose` the image when the control is `Dispose`d, but not all properties seem to work that way.  `Font` properties seem really weird...

Comment: ...since one set a control's `Font` property to an already-disposed font and the control won't mind.  I don't know if that's a good or bad idea, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 6):

this [article](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) is very helpful, in the Memory Disposal section.

All classes that implement IDisposable (including all Windows Forms controls) have a Dispose method.  This method must be called when an object is no longer needed in order to release resources other than memory.  There are two ways this happens:

- manually (by calling Dispose explicitly)
- automatically: by adding the object to a .NET container, such as a Form, Panel, TabPage or 
  UserControl.  The container will ensure that when it’s disposed, so are all of its members.  Of course, the container itself must be disposed (or in turn, be part of another container).
  In the case of Windows Forms controls, we nearly always add them to a container – and hence rely on automatic disposal.

Answer (score 2):

Lot of different answers here ..

I strongly advise to read [Garbage Collector Basics and Performance Hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx)
In you case you've two option:

- Dispose the ImageList manually, so the ressource will be released
  quickly (but not immediately)
- Do nothing: the resources will be release next time the Garbage
  Collector analyse the Generation where you form is. If you form is
  closed, and nothing keep a reference to your form, then your form
  will be disposed, and then as no reference will point to the
  ImageList anymore, the ImageList will be disposed. The resources
  will be released, but a bit later than the first case.

Except if you have thousand of big images in your ImageList (or if you create/close the form hundred of times), you'll not notice any difference between the 2 cases

Comment: GC has nothing to do with what i asked. When some class represents or holds a native resource (which ImageList may hold, i am not sure), it needs to be properly disposed. The GC looks for object roots (which objects are still accessible) and collects ones that cannot be accessed anymore. This does not mean that these objects are "Disposed" (meaning that the resources that they are holding will be freed correctly). My question was specifically regarding WinForms and whether i can have my objects automatically disposed somehow by the form itself.

Comment: GC calls the Finalize method of object and developer call the Dispose method. Both are related to freeing resource, which is done by the GC. So yes, your question is related to the GC. If the ImageList handle native resource, it's his job to release it by implementing the Finalize method (and that's the case because ImageList inherit from Component). Developer can accelerate that by calling the dispose method, but you'll not have a memory leak if you don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you have posted, you are not using Designer to implement this control. Thus, you will not have a designer-provided `Dispose(bool disposing)` method or a `System.CompononetModel.IContainer components` member that your extra control may be added to. I am not sure how ListBox handles its `Controls` property, but if it lets you register your `ImageList` instance there with `Controls.Add(ImageList)`, that should get you the automatic `Dispose()` behavior.

Your other option is to override `Control.Dispose(bool)` like the following:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    // Only call Dispose() on members if invoked through a direct
    // call to `Dispose()`. (If disposing is false, that means
    // we are invoked through the finalizer and we should *only*
    // free up unmanaged resources that we *directly* own).
    if (disposing)
    {
        ImageList.Dispose();
    }

    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```