# Call garbage collector after ImageList.Items.Clear()?

Tags: c#, listview, garbage-collection, imagelist

#Context:

Generating PNGs from PDF pages and showing them in a ListView through an ImageList

#Desired behaviour:

When the user chooses another file to be displayed in the listview -> clear both the ImageList and ListView items (obvious) and also delete the generated image files.

#Issue:

Exception thrown on delete: "The process cannot access the file 'X.png' because it is being used by another process."

```
previewImageList.Images.Clear();
previewListView.Items.Clear();

// folder containing the generated PNGs, created at runtime
string folderToDelete = Path.Combine(outputFolder, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(selectedSong));

try
{                
  Directory.Delete(folderToDelete, true);  // Image file "X.png" is used by another process
}
catch (Exception)
{}
```

Solution found:

- calling the Garbage Collector manually before deleting the said PNG files seems to do the trick.

  previewImageList.Images.Clear();
  previewListView.Items.Clear();

  string folderToDelete = Path.Combine(outputFolder, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(selectedSong));

  try
  {
  GC.Collect();
  GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

  ```
  Directory.Delete(folderToDelete, true);
  ```

  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }

**But** *as i researched* so far it isn't a good thing to do.
Do I have an alternative to calling the Garbage collector?
The reason I need to delete the PNGs is to be able to reuse respective filename with a PDF from another path...

The closest I got to are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219407/where-is-the-proper-place-to-dispose-an-image/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634512/winforms-and-disposing-custom-controls) but didn't help much.

**EDIT additional details**
Generating the PNGs:

- i use [ImageMagik](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) like this:

  startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
  startInfo.FileName = """ + UtilitiesFolder + "\convert.exe"";
  startInfo.Arguments = """ + selectedPDFFile.pdf" + "" "
  + " -resample 168x140 ""
  + Path.Combine(outputFolder, selectedPDFFileShortName) + ".png" + """;
  startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
  startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
  startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
  startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

  process = Process.Start(startInfo);
  process.WaitForExit(5000); // wait no more than 5 seconds

  if (process.HasExited)
  { //good
  }
  else{
  //abort everything
  }

Loading images into ImageList & ListView:

```
void previewSelectedPresentation(string presentationName)
{
  previewImageList.Images.Clear();
  previewListView.Items.Clear();
            
  DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\\test\\" + presentationName);
            
  foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
  {
    try
    {
      this.previewImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file.FullName));
    }
    catch
    {
      Console.WriteLine("This is not an image file");
    }
  }

  for (int j = 0; j < this.previewImageList.Images.Count; j++)
  {
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
    item.ImageIndex = j;
    item.Text = (j + 1).ToString();                
    this.previewListView.Items.Add(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why invoking the `gc` is bad?

Comment: Show the code where you are loading the .png files.  If you're using Bitmap.FromFile then that may be what is locking the file.

Comment: @Tudor, it *is* bad; it's a very expensive operation, and the runtime usually knows better than you when the GC should run.

Comment: @DenisC, how are you generating the images? Are you closing the file after you do? Please show the relevant code.

Comment: This went wrong a long time ago, you forgot to dispose the images after you added them to the ImageList.  That it makes a copy of the image isn't exactly crystal-clear.

Comment: GC.Collect() is not a command to the runtime to run the collector, merely a hint that it may want to do so at its next available opportunity. Any code that relies on the collector running at the point that GC.Collect() is called is wrong and requires rework.

Comment: @HansPassant: I found the solution but I'll post my answer next morning as my rep doesn't allow me now :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Per Hans Passant above, 
(paraphrasing)

> This went wrong a long time ago. I forgot to dispose the images after I
>   added them to the ImageList.

So here's the correct way to add into ImageList (please see original question for comparison) - changes signaled by comment:

```
void previewSelectedPresentation(string presentationName)
{
  previewImageList.Images.Clear();
  previewListView.Items.Clear();

  DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\\test\\" + presentationName);

  foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
  {
    try
    {  
       // these three lines have changed
       Image slideImage = Image.FromFile(file.FullName);  // change 1
       this.previewImageList.Images.Add(slideImage);      // change 2
       slideImage.Dispose();                              // change 3
    }
    catch
    {
      Console.WriteLine("This is not an image file");
    }
  }

  for (int j = 0; j < this.previewImageList.Images.Count; j++)
  {
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
    item.ImageIndex = j;
    item.Text = (j + 1).ToString();                
    this.previewListView.Items.Add(item);
  }          
}
```

Cleaning up works now without calling the GC.
Thanks for helping me figure this out myself!
Also, helpful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639237/imagelist-disposing-the-original-image-removes-it-from-the-list).